# Linq Lambda Error : The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I receive this error, and I tried a lot to solve it, but I receive other errors, is there a solution?

```cs
using (var contextDb1 = new Db1Context(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DB1ConnectionString"].ToString(), false))
{
    using (var contextDb2 = new Db2Context(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DB2ConnectionString"].ToString(), false))
    {   
        var messagesList = contextDb2.Messages
            .Select(m => new MessagesViewModel
            {
                UserName = contextDb1.UsersInfo.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.Id == m.UserId).UserName,
                MessageId = m.MessageId,
                MessageText = m.MessageText,
                DateTime = m.DateTime
            })
            .ToList();

        return messagesList;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to synchronize two databases via LINQ and EF?

Comment: Try to fetch the contextDb1.UsersInfo in user defined type list before fetching messages and make use that list to fetch the user name.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv In the second database (Db2) I have a table with messages with IDs of the users who wrote the messages, but the user information such as the username is in another database (Db1), and I would like to display the messages with usernames... but I'm getting the above error

Comment: @Smits , I'm sorry I didn't understand you well, in fact I tried many solutions to no avail , I don't know what to do, can you correct the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query two different databases via the same LINQ Query. But you can use intermediate result to execute two queries to databases and then combine result.

```cs
using (var contextDb1 = new Db1Context(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DB1ConnectionString"].ToString(), false))
using (var contextDb2 = new Db2Context(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DB2ConnectionString"].ToString(), false))
{   
    var rawMessages = contextDb2.Messages
        .Select(m => new 
        {
            m.UserId
            m.MessageId,
            m.MessageText,
            m.DateTime
        })
        .ToList();

    var userIds = rawMessages.Select(x => xu.UserId);
    
    var usersInfo = contextDb1.UsersInfo.Where(u => userIds.Contains(u.Id))
        .Select(u =>  new 
        {
            UserId = u.Id,
            UserName = u.UserName
        });

    var messageQuery = 
        from m in rawMessages
        join u in usersInfo.AsEnumerable() on m.UserId equals u.UserId into gj
        from u in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new MessagesViewModel
        {
            UserName = u?.UserName,
            MessageId = m.MessageId,
            MessageText = m.MessageText,
            DateTime = m.DateTime
        };
    
    var messagesList = messageQuery.ToList();

    return messagesList;   
}
```

Comment: Another approach to consider is to put the two DB contexts into separate methods. Create a 3rd method that call these two methods and then transform the final output there. That may help with following stack traces on where things fail should these queries are not guaranteed to be always available.